# select 10 parents with all of their childs

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a simple table: `id`, `parent_id`, `content`

items with `parent_id = 0` are parents, and items with `parent_id > 0` are children

Now I want to select 10 parents with all of their children

With 2 query its simple to get parents in query 1 and then all children in query 2

but I want it be done in 1 query

I have written this, but it's not working:

```
select * 
from blogs 
where parent_id in (select id 
                    from blogs 
                    where parent_id = 0 
                    order by id desc 
                    limit 10) 
union all 
select * 
from blogs 
where parent_id = 0 
order by id 
desc limit 10
```

Comment: what this generates? and what is your mysql version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check below mentioned solution.

```
SELECT 
    t1.id as parent_id,
    t1.content as parent,
    GROUP_CONCAT(t2.content) as children
from blogs t1
INNER JOIN blogs t2 ON t2.parent_id = t1.id
WHERE t1.parent_id = 0
GROUP BY t1.id
LIMIT 10;
```

Please change `table_name` and `field_name` in above query.
Let me know if it not work for you.

Comment: Share your query

Comment: replace this `t1.id as parent_id, t1.* as parent, GROUP_CONCAT(t2.*) as children` with  `t1.id as parent_id,t1.content as parent,GROUP_CONCAT(t2.content) as children`

Comment: If you want entire row of parent then use below query. `SELECT 
 t1.*, 
 GROUP_CONCAT(t2.content) as children 
from test t1 
INNER JOIN test t2 ON t2.parent_id = t1.id 
WHERE t1.parent_id = 0 
GROUP BY t1.id 
LIMIT 10;`